# can not copy records to a table with reference key

Tags: mysql

I have a table, say, table2 that is connected with parent table, table1. I also have table3, which I want to copy its content to table2 that is connected to table1. Table3 may have some values in the foreign key column that are not available in table1 & this causes an error when I try to copy the values. How can I solve this problem in order to copy only the records that have a reference in the parent table ??

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
insert into table2 (col1, col2, ...)
select col1, col2, ... from table3
where table3.refcol in (select keycol from table1)
```

Of course you need to replace samples with actual column names. :-)

Comment: This is much less efficient than the join used in the answer posted by kaps.

Comment: Stating such without knowing actual data types, table sizes and indexes in use is quite strange... I'd recommend a little trust in mysql's query optimizer ;)

Comment: Hi Kuba. My comment applies regardless of data types, table sizes, or indexes. Emulating joins using IN() is an anti-pattern.

Comment: OK, I don't want to argue (much ;-) 1. I executed both statements in SQL2005 (got no MySQL here) and - as I expected - it created identical execution plans for both variants. 2. I would personally use inner joins I am used to as well, but... 3. ...I believe that for JuryA, who is asking such a question the "IN" version is much more readable and understandable. And I wouldn't call it "anti-pattern" though. :-) Regards.

Comment: And I believe execution plans would differ if there WAS a relation between Table3 and Table1, but it's an opposite case here obviously.

Comment: Maybe MSSQL is better, but MySQL performance is notoriously bad for dynamic IN() clauses. Also, from my reading of the question there is at least an implicit foreign key relationship between table3 and table1.

Comment: Yeah, and database servers are commonly known to make extensive use of implicit relationships. :]

Answer (score 1):

```
Insert into Table2 (<columnList>)
Select <columnlist> 
From Table3 Inner join Table1
On Table3.fieldFromTable3 = Table1.ReferredFieldFromTable1
```

Use the columns as you want in  and provide appropriate field names in Join.